# Package only runs with S3, "this S4 class is not subsettable"

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I want to apply the `margins` package to an `s4` output.

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function
library(VGAM)
library(margins)
rm(df1)
df1 <- df1
df1$x2 <- df2$y
df1$x3 <- df2$x
df1$y <- df3$x/10
```

Here are two packages. One has `s3`  output and one `s4`

```
fit.polr.s3 <- polr(x2 ~ x + x3, data = df1, method = "probit") # S3
fit.polr.s4  <- vglm(x2 ~ x + x3, family=propodds, data=df1) # S4

summary(margins(fit.polr.s3, variables = "x", typ="response"))

 factor    AME     SE      z      p   lower  upper
      x 0.0011 0.0010 1.0853 0.2778 -0.0009 0.0031
```

But:

```
summary(margins(fit.polr.s4, variables = "x", typ="response"))

Error in `*tmp*`[["coefficients"]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

I need the `VGAM` function, is there anyway to convert the output back to `s3`. Or make the package accept `s4`.

I am pretty sure that the only issue is how `@` instead of `$` should be used. I tried to replace it in the package but if I type `margins` in `R`. It only shows:

```
function (model, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("margins")
}
<bytecode: 0x000001c2ebaca028>
<environment: namespace:margins>
```

## EDIT:

Running `fit.polr.s4$coefficients <- fit.polr.s4@coefficients` gives the error: `Error in $<-(*tmp*, coefficients, value = c((Intercept):1 = 3.03597808578146,  :  no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class`.

```
> class(fit.polr.s4)
[1] "vglm"
attr(,"package")
[1] "VGAM"
```

Comment: Sounds like you've hit a limitation of the margins package. It could be a bug or a known limitation. Have you got a reason to expect that `margins` will work for a VGAM class?

Comment: BTW to see the methods for margins, type `margins:::margins.` and hit tab. Note the THREE colons, for private functions, and the dot at the end. Or use `methods("margins")`.

Comment: as a workaround, does calling `fit.polr.s4$coefficients <- fit.polr.s4@coefficients` solve the problem?

Comment: @JDL Thank you for your comment. Running `fit.polr.s4$coefficients <- fit.polr.s4@coefficients` gives the error: `Error in $<-(*tmp*, coefficients, value = c((Intercept):1 = 3.03597808578146,  :  no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class`.

Comment: okay --- what class is the s4 object? (i.e. what is the result of `class(fit.polr.s4)`?)

Comment: @JDL See second part of the edit (I am adding all your suggestions to the post for clarity)